# Thunderbird: History of seen Messages

Tags: thunderbird, history, usability

Is there a way in thunderbird to step backward and forward in the history of last messages? Like in firefox: It has a history of the last visited pages.

I would like to have a history of the last messages I looked at.

Can you understand what I want? Please ask if not, I am not a native speaker.

**Update**

Like Rinzwind suggested, I opened a feature request: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1313349

Comment: To track every mail, I usually open all of the required ones in different tabs.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Thunderbird does not have that kind of feature.  Don't think I have seen it in any kind of mail program to be honest.

Though I do like the idea and it only would require a field "when read" so you can sort on it. I would suggest to file an [enhancement request](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Thunderbird&bug_severity=enhancement).

Comment: thank you for your feedback, I created a feature request. See above.

Comment: I got a notice when you edited the question ;-)